# RStudio Viewer cannot show localhosts locations, but can show 127.0.0.1 locations

Tags: localhost, rstudio, plotly

## Problem

For some reason my RStudio (v1.0.136) stopped showing plotly (v4.5.6) graphs in the Viewer.
When I right-click and `Inspect element` I can see the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.  
http://localhost:14985/session/viewhtmle0e7ad97b99/index.html?viewer_pane=1
```

Opening that link in Chrome shows the plot, so the file is there.

When I run these commands in RStudio:

```
viewer <- getOption("viewer")
viewer("http://localhost:14985/session/viewhtmle0e7ad97b99/index.html?viewer_pane=1")
```

I get the same error. But, if I replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`:

```
viewer <- getOption("viewer")
viewer("http://127.0.0.1:14985/session/viewhtmle0e7ad97b99/index.html?viewer_pane=1")
```

The plot shows as expected in the Viewer window.

## Attempts

I have restored my `/etc/hosts` file (content, ownership and permissions). This did not result in any other behaviour.
I have checked the output of `lsof | grep localhost`:

```
RStudio   57564 user   12u    IPv4 0x746dc97144b1de71        0t0      TCP localhost:53434->localhost:27978 (ESTABLISHED)
RStudio   57564 user   13u    IPv4 0x746dc97144b1de71        0t0      TCP localhost:53434->localhost:27978 (ESTABLISHED)
rsession  57575 user    5u    IPv4 0x746dc97144868c81        0t0      TCP localhost:27978 (LISTEN)
rsession  57575 user    6u    IPv4 0x746dc9714568c769        0t0      TCP localhost:27978->localhost:53434 (ESTABLISHED)
rsession  57575 user   19u    IPv4 0x746dc97145a1c061        0t0      TCP localhost:14985 (LISTEN)
```

And to me it seems that the `rsession` is listening to the correct port on localhost.

I have also turned off the Mac OS firewall, this did not have any effect.

I have turned off Little Snitch (a firewall for outgoing connection) as well, this did not have any effect.

### Update 2017-02-15:

I have found that this behaviour is dependent on the network I am connected to.

- Work Ethernet - all OK
- Home wifi - Issue as described above
- Android wifi hotspot - all OK
- Wifi adapter switched off - new error in the `Inspect element` window: Failed to load resource: The Internet connection appears to be offline``

What network setting can affect plotly's interaction with RStudio's Viewer?